# Which shell message are involved, in my example, and how to enable or disable them?

Tags: command-line, bash

I have two Ubuntu virtualboxes both version 16.04.

If to reset the network manager on vbox1 results in :

```
bernard@vbox1~$ sudo service network-manager restart
bernard@vbox1~$
```

and tests suggested by muru :

```
bernard@vBox1:~$ type -a service
service is /usr/sbin/service
bernard@vBox1:~$

bernard@vBox1:~$ sudo ls -l /proc/1/exe   
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 feb 11 13:47 /proc/1/exe -> /lib/systemd/systemd
bernard@vBox1:~$ 

bernard@vBox1:~$  dpkg -S /usr/*bin/service
init-system-helpers: /usr/sbin/service
bernard@vBox1:~$
```

So just the prompt, I type the statement, and the prompt is returned when the statement is executed.

On the other virtualbox however I do the same, but wit a different result.

```
bernard@vbox11:~$ sudo service network-manager restart
network-manager stop/waiting
network-manager start/running, process 2667
bernard@vbox11:~$
```

and

```
bernard@vbox11:~$ type -a service
service is /usr/sbin/service
service is /usr/bin/service
bernard@vbox11:~$ 

bernard@vbox11:~$ sudo ls -l /proc/1/exe
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 feb 13 17:23 /proc/1/exe -> /sbin/init
bernard@vbox11:~$

bernard@vbox11:~$ dpkg -S /usr/*bin/service
sysvinit-utils: /usr/bin/service
sysvinit-utils: /usr/sbin/service
bernard@vbox11:~$
```

So some messages are displayed.

Which shell (bash) messages are these? 
How these messages can be enabled and disabled?

It seems to me it be a configuration of bash. but in ~/.config/.bashrc I can not find a configuration variable.

Comment: What *versions* of Ubuntu are running on the two virtual machines? I suspect you are just seeing differences in the init mechanism that's being invoked under the hood by the `service` command (`systemd` versus `upstart`)

Comment: Edit your post to include the output of `type -a service` and `ls -l /prof/1/exe`, please

Comment: @muru I added your first test. There is indeed a difference. The second test failed : bernard@vBox1:~$ ls -l /prof/1/exe
ls: cannot access '/prof/1/exe': No such file or directory
bernard@vBox1:~$

Comment: @steeldriver I added the Ubunto version. Both are equal  16.04

Comment: @Bernard autocorrect, that should have been `proc` instead of `prof`. Also, add the output of `dpkg -S /usr/*bin/service` as well

Comment: @muru. I added your tests. and I see there is a difference now. Can this difference be configured?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 by default comes with `systemd`, assuming you didn't change your init system, which means it's very odd that you have two same OS versions, yet they differ.  Unless, of course, you're mistaken and installed wrong version in vbox2

Comment: @Serg That was not the question. Yes indeed I have to Ubuntu 16.04. With vbox11  I did run all updates, with vbox1 and did not do so yet. I am reluctant with updates, because a update may disrupt a good working system.

Comment: @Bernard that directly influences your question.  The type of init system you have determines the type of output messages you get.

Comment: @bernard also, it has nothing to do with updates. If you  installed 16.04, as you say, and didn't upgrade from older version, then what potentially happened is that you configured one with systemd and one with upstart.

Comment: @Serg it was not a clean install. It was an upgrade from 14.04. But both where an upgrade.